# Does a neo4j 2.0 Cypher query need a WITH statement between CREATE UNIQUE and MATCH?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This query used to work in Neo4j 1.9 without the `WITH` statement in between the `CREATE UNIQUE` and `MATCH` statements.

```
START left=node:node_auto_index(Uname = "test"),
right=node:node_auto_index("StoreId:(\"com.google.android.street\",\"com.google.android.youtube.googletv\")")
CREATE UNIQUE left-[:Owns]->(Device {DeviceId:"myDevice"} ) <-[r:Installed]-right 
WITH left, right
MATCH right-[:InstanceOf]->parents<-[?:Alternative]-altParents<-[:InstanceOf]-alternatives   
RETURN right AS App;
```

Why was there the change in 2.0, is the query with the `WITH` keyword the correct way of doing things? Does this have any difference in performance?  I'm assuming not.

Comment: What happens if you leave off `WITH` in 2.0 ?

Comment: I get an error saying `} expected but got : instead`

Comment: if I leave off `WITH`I get: Error: expected valid query body
"MATCH right-[:InstanceOf]->parents<-[?:Alternative]-altParents<-[:InstanceOf]-alternatives "

Comment: reported it to the team as an issue, watch the changelog, sorry for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the error is with the 1.9 parser and not the 2.0 parser. Cypher doesn't allow you to mix reading and writing in the same sub query, and START..MATCH...CREATE UNIQUE...MATCH does just that.

The new 2.0 parser is stricter and correctly refuses this query.